# What should I do?(TypeError)

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

```
import re

ffail = ""
with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , "UTF-8") as some_file:
    ffail = some_file.read()
count = 0

match = re.findall('[0-9]+', ffail)

for II in match:
    number = int(II)
    count = count + number
print(count)
```

This code gives me this error:
    with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , "UTF-8") as some_file:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Answer (score 1):

`open`'s third argument is `buffering` ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)), not `encoding`, so you need to pass `encoding` as a keyword argument. Also, it's better to use `"utf8"`.

```
with open("regex_sum_340933.txt", "r" , encoding="utf8") as some_file:
```

Comment: putting the encoding thing it gives me:           File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 8: invalid continuation byte